Consultation about static analysis tool infer for neverreturn problems in child functions
Vulnerability comparison page
Vulnerability details page
infer computational results
NP Result details
After opening space through malloc, if it is determined that the opening address is empty, the program stops running. If you call exit in the die function to stop the function, infer reports a null pointer reference. If you use exit to end the process, infer does not report an error. However, die and exit have similar functions.
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
//void *die(const char *msg,void *section) 
void *die()
{ 
    exit(1);
}
     
int main()
{ 
    int* a = malloc(10);
    if( a == NULL)
    { 
        exit(1); 
        //die();
    } 
    int b = *a;
    printf("%d",b);
}

I wonder why the infer tool makes such judgments when the execution logic of the two types of code is exactly the same.

There are compiler-specific attributes that can be set on function to tell the compiler it will not return. And from the C23 standard, the noreturn attribute. As for your shown code, why did you declare the function to return a value (a generic pointer)? What happens if you change the return-type from void * to void?

When I replace it with void the result doesn't change, the null pointer problem still occurs
